# A PHP Error was encountered Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the comments of teachers to display but I keep getting this error:

***Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property 'teacher_comment' of non-object
Filename: student/getstudent.php
Line Number: 3148***

### **model**

```
public function GetTeacherComment($student_id, $session_id) 
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('student_id', $student_id);
        $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
        return $this->db->get('teacher_comments')->row();
    }
```

### **controller**

```
$data['teacher_comment'] = $this->Comment_model->GetTeacherComment($id, $student_session_id);
```

### **view**

```
<span style=" bottom: -20px; position: relative;"> <color style="color:blue;"> CLASS TEACHER'S REMARK:</color> <b
                                                style="text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $teacher_comment->teacher_comment; ?> </b></span><br>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your call to `GetTeacherComment` is returning an object? Try running `var_dump($data)` before you pass `$data` to your view to see what the properties look like.

Comment: You should check if `$teacher_comment` actually has data and is not empty. If not, then check if you're spelling the column name correct.

Comment: @sauhardnc thanks, I have resolved it. The $student_session_id in the controller did not get the right session_id.

Comment: @MamaJardel ok, no issues.